# Need to analyse a set of JS files using flow

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I want to run flowtype on my existing project(Against a set of JS files), and I want to see the results in one place/file separately. Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just run `flow status`. You need to follow the [setup instructions](https://flowtype.org/docs/getting-started.html#_) first of course. In particular, make sure you have a `.flowconfig` file at the root of your project (it can be empty), and make sure that you have `// @flow` at the beginning of the files you want checked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, I am executing flow using npm, so will flow always look for a package.json file? I am getting error saying this when i run from different locations

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. It might be easier to understand if you provided the entire error text. In any case, it sounds like it would likely be more appropriate as a separate top-level question.